# One hundred and fifty-one or one hundred fifty-one?

Tags: word-usage

One hundred and fifty-one or one hundred fifty-one?

Which is right? When should I have and and should not I have and?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect - and American contributors will soon put me right if I'm wrong - that Americans tend to omit the **and** while UK practice is to include it.

Certainly, my experience (in Europe, Australia and Africa) has always been to include the **and**, while I've often heard it omitted on north American radio and TV channels.

Grammar Monster - sourced below - advises people to include the **and** but I suspect this is more a question of geography and style than correctness.

https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/numbers_how_to_write_in_full.htm

Comment: How about 101 in full?

Comment: In writing, you need the "and" in AmE. Speech can be either way.

Answer (score 0):

The word “and” is used ONLY to speak mixed numbers.
For example, 1 1/2 is spoken “one and one-half”, and
1.5   is spoken “one and five tenths”.

125 is correctly spoken “one hundred twenty-five”.
If you choose to speak “one hundred and twenty-five” which is what 90%+ of Americans say, not a big deal unless you take pride in speaking correctly.

The problem occurs when the same person speaks .125 as
“one hundred and twenty five thousandths” which is the number 100.025.
.125 is correctly spoken “one hundred twenty-five thousandths.“

But it’s a rare occasion because most people speak
.125 as “point one, two, five.

How would the “I use the “and” people” speak 125.125?
I hear “one hundred and twenty-five and one hundred and twenty-five thousandths”.  But one rarely hears the decimal part of a mixed number spoken correctly and we most likely would hear “one hundred and twenty-five point one, two, five or “a hundred and twenty-five point one, two, five”.